# Delphi + Windows Text Services Framework

Tags: delphi, text-services-framework

Is there any way to use / integrate Delphi application with Text Services Framework?

I'm thinking especially about InputScope.h stuff (like ITfInputScope / SetInputScopes)

VCL framework is hooked by default only with ITextInputPanel (PenInputPanel.h)...

Comment: What is stopping you from doing this?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do?   If you're trying to add TSF support to your existing text controls, then yes, that's reasonably straightforward.